# Handle two independent content containers on same page

Tags: ember.js

I am using ember.js to develop a single page app. I have a dashboard with two different content sections which are independent of each other (so it is not a master/detail relationship).

The structure is like this (using Haml):

```
#dashboard
  #top
    %nav
    .content
  #bottom
    %nav
    .content
```

In both #top and #bottom there is a little navigation which changes the content of #top and #bottom independently. What is the ember way to

1. Load the initial state of the dashboard (with default content for #top and #bottom)
2. Load new content for #top or #bottom using the corresponding navigation. Loading new content into #top should not change or remove content already present in #bottom and vice versa.

I am still learning ember.js. I hope this question makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make these various dashboard states routable (expressible as URLs), you'll need to come up with a URL scheme that allows for independent navigation. Let's say the top and bottom sections each could have "foo", "bar", or "baz" as the current pane. I would suggest

```
/dashboard/foo;bar
```

or

```
/dashboard/foo+bar
```

Now that you've picked a URL scheme, you need to tell the router how to serialize and deserialize the scheme. Resource routes expect a model, so we'll fake one:

```
App.DashboardPages = Ember.Object.extend({
  top:    Ember.required(),
  bottom: Ember.required(),
});

App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('dashboard', { path: '/dashboard/:pages' });
});

App.DashboardRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function(params) {
    // TODO: error handling for bad URLs

    var pages      = params.pages.split('+');

    return App.DashboardPages.create({
      top:    pages[0],
      bottom: pages[1]
    });
  },

  serialize: function(model) {
    return {
      pages: "%@+%@".fmt(model.get('top'), model.get('bottom'))
    };
  }
});
```

Then, in your `DashboardController`, you can pick child views based on the `DashboardPages` "model".

Comment: One tricky bit I haven't worked out is how to build links for the nav sections of each half. The link generator will have to know the *other* section's current state.

Comment: Guess the resource path would be `{path: '/dashboard/:pages'}`, right?

Comment: So in the `DashboardController`, how would I render the child views? Isn't it the task of route to render views through `renderTemplate`?

Comment: Good catch on the `path`; fixed.Your template (or view) would have to use the `top` and `bottom` properties to choose what to render.

Comment: Sorry for my late response. Was distracted by other projects. So for me the tricky part seems to be how and where to render the correct templates for the top and bottom dashboard parts. I tried to create a `dashboard` template with two outlets `top` and `bottom`, but I can't figure out where to render in the outlets. Or do I need some conditional logic in the `dashboard` template to render a subtemplate? How would you do this?